# sql error or missing database (no such table found)

Tags: java, jdbc

I am working on eclipse and using sqlite as database on windows 10 64 bit operating system. Now when i try to get all values from my database it shows the message that there is no such table but the connection is being established. 
What should i do??

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C://Users//APARAJIT//Desktop//Projects//kbcc.sqlite");
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"can't open database");
}

try {
    Statement stmt = mycon.createStatement();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM record";
    PreparedStatement pst = mycon.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

    rs.close();
    pst.close();
    stmt.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, e);
}
```

Comment: i think the message says it all...

Comment: You might have to choose / set the schema before querying from the table from default schema ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: path to project folder]

Please copy your database file to your project folder. 
I faced the same error. The reason for that error is because of my sqlite database file being in my `src` folder. When I move it from my `src` folder to my project folder, my error is solved.

Comment: this worked Alhamdulillah,  but question is Can This included the db when I create Jar ?

Answer (score 0):

Query your database directly from the schema that your program uses, with the exact statement you have in your code. That way you can figure out if you actually created the table already or not.

Comment: In my previous program i used the same query and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the table name spell or table does exist or not please

Comment: checked the table name and then i tried to create another database and the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

change this `conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C://Users//APARAJIT//Desktop//Projects//kbcc.sqlite");`

test

```
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C://Users/APARAJIT/Desktop/Projects/kbcc.sqlite");
```

my example:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C://sqlite/db/datosplayer.db";
```

Answer (score -2):

**If your connection is good, then your table name is not.**

Check the spelling of the table you're using.
Check the case of your table and column names. Names are case sensitive.

You can verify these through a SQLite browser/GUI.